# Vector projection formula

Tags: linear-algebra

How can i prove that

> proj(x,y) =[(x∘y)/||y||^2]*y for every x,y vector such as x,y∈R^N

I have a proof that i have been working on that I am not sure if it is correct.

Proof: We know that the projection of vector x to vector y is a vector like c*y.
We need to find the proper c so that ||x-c*y|| is the closest to 0 it can.

> F(c) = ||x - cy|| = (x - cy) ∘ (x - cy) = ||x||^2 - 2cx∘y + c^2||y||^2

We assume that

> 0 =dF/dc= -2x∘y + 2c||y||^2 ==> c = x∘y/||y||^2

So

> proj(x,y) =[(x∘y)/|y|^2]*y

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your proof is correct.